# How to make the TensorFlow map() function return multiple values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-augmentation

I am trying to write a function that will augment images from a dataset. I am able to successfully augment an existing image and return it, but I want to be able to do multiple augmentations on a single image and return those augmented images individually and then add them to the original dataset.

Augmentation function:

```
def augment_data(image, label):

h_flipped_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
v_flipped_image = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)

return h_flipped_image, label
```

Map function:

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(augment_data)
```

train_ds is tf.data Dataset with with the following shape:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 224, 224, 3), (None, 238)), types: (tf.float32, tf.bool)>
```

How can I make the map function return multiple value in such a way that I could, for example, return both the h_flipped_image and the v_flipped_image and add them to the train_ds dataset?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Tensorflow, but this is just how mapping works in general.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did some more research and it appears that it indeed might not be possible to make the map function return multiple samples and have them added to the dataset. I found a different solution to my problem (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was not looking at the problem from the right direction. I realized that I do not need the augmented samples to be included in the dataset after all. Instead I chose to opt for augmenting the data during the training process.

Since the training process will take multiple epochs I can just augment the image right before the network needs it. I did this by modifying my augment_data function, so it now has a random chance to perform a certain augmentation. Each epoch a random combination of augmentations will be performed on the image resulting in a different input image for the network each time.

```
def augment_data(image, label):

rand = tf.random.uniform([])
if(rand > 0.5):
    image = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)

# Additional augmented techniques should be defined here

return image, label
```

Make sure you use a TensorFlow function for generating the random number. A simple random.random() will not work due to the way TensorFlow interprets python code.